# How to specify filter files using xsbt filter?

Tags: sbt

I was using [xsbt-filter](https://github.com/sdb/xsbt-filter) to do resources filtering.
Now I have two filter files: test.properties and product.propertes.
But how to specify which filter to be used like maven command `mvn -Pproduct package` by using sbt?